# Проверить, что данные имеют нормальный закон распределения

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, статистика, поиск-библиотек

При помощи критериев Колмогорова, Крамера-Мизеса и Андерсона-Дарлинга проверить гипотезу о том, что данные имеют нормальный закон распределения с  средним и дисперсией. Возможно кто-то уже использовал какие-то библиотеки для проведения данных тестов или знает как реализовать данные тесты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека scipy.stats:

Колмогорова - kstest()

Андерсона-Дарлинга -  anderson()

Библиотека statsmodels:

Андерсона-Дарлинга - normal_ad()